# Gerrit - find the review comments globally

Tags: gerrit

Is there any way to globally search review comments, given by other user. I tried `message:"some word to search"` in the gerrit search engine, however this is not the right way to find. I need to search using some common known string, like `"remove this extra line"`, it should show all the matching review comments given by any user and should populate all such stories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should search using `comment:text` instead of `message:text`

```
message:'MESSAGE'
Changes that match 'MESSAGE' arbitrary string in the commit message body.

comment:'TEXT'
Changes that match 'TEXT' string in any comment left by a reviewer.
```